Ignoring extra columns when copying CSV data to Redshift table
I'm loading CSV data into an Amazon Redshift table from an S3 bucket using the COPY command. The CSV file contains columns firstname, lastname, and dateofbirth, but sometimes it may contain extra columns which do not match the columns in my Redshift table. When this happens, the COPY command fails.
Here's my current COPY command:
COPY schema.user (firstname, lastname, dateofbirth)
      FROM 's3://.../user.csv' -- S3 URI
      IAM_ROLE '...' -- ARN
      CSV
      TIMEFORMAT 'auto'
      IGNOREHEADER 1
      DATEFORMAT 'auto'
      EMPTYASNULL
      REGION AS '...' --Amazon region;

Is there a way to modify the COPY command so that Redshift only reads the required columns (firstname, lastname, and dateofbirth) from the CSV file and ignores any additional columns, preventing the copy operation from failing?
My table is created with the following schema:
CREATE TABLE schema.user (
          id char(36),
          firstname character varying(256) ENCODE lzo,
          lastname character varying(256) ENCODE lzo,
          dateofbirth date ENCODE az64
        ) DISTSTYLE AUTO;


Are the additional columns always to the right of the data you want in the CSV file?
